# alt+H is not working

Tags: shortcut

why my alt+h shortcut is not working? I can go to menu and reveal it. but still i want to know why it stopped working?

I am using hp 15-ay503TX, Intel i5-6th generation, radeon graphics and OS- windows 8.1.

I am just learning modeling from YouTube. and I didn't wanted some part of my mesh to be affected by proportional editing. so I hid it. and then I pressed alt+h but it was not working.

Comment: What is the context in which this is occurring? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: check if it is working with the standard cube: if not, your shortcut map could have been changed, somehow...